# How to use transparency in Webview2?

Tags: c#, webview2

On C#, how to use transparency in Webview2?
Is it possible?

Does it work in WebBrowser but not WebView2?

[image: Comparison]

Answer (score 10):

You can change the [WebView2.DefaultBackgroundColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.wpf.webview2.defaultbackgroundcolor?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.864.35) (which defaults to white) to transparent to have a transparent background:

```cs
webView2.DefaultBackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
```

The [WebView2 WPF sample app](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/blob/2449abc2a0c0b04e73fc0c06673b4c0643e35c00/SampleApps/WebView2WpfBrowser/MainWindow.xaml.cs#L368) demonstrates this feature.
[image: WebView2 WPF sample app with a transparent background set for the WebView2]

Comment: On UWP with WInUI 3 it shows the WebView does not contain any definition for DefaultBackgroundColor. Any idea about that?