# How to set BlazorWebView transparent in MAUI app

Tags: blazor, maui, maui-windows

How can I set the background of the BlazorWebView to be transparent instead of white?

I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67844651/758083) is what I need to do, but I'm not seeing how to use a handler to make this change.

Comment: Perhaps `<BlazorWebView BackgroundColor="Transparent">`. But a `BlazorWebView` is an element within a Maui ContentView or ContentPage, so what you will see behind it is most likely the background color of that view|page. Are you asking how to make the Maui window itself be transparent?